# java to C++ conversion simple 1 liner

Tags: java, c++

i am trying to decipher a java source but i write in c++. what is the conversion for the below 1 line of code. Im not keen on java syntax.

java->c++
it is a declaration

```
 Node[] vlist;
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have anything identical, but an obvious choice would be `std::vector<Node> vlist;`

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer to an array of pointers.
Note that Java arrays remember their length.

```
Node **vlist;
int vlist_length;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a `Node` array. Similar way you can define this in c++.

```
Node vList[] // initialize
```

[Arrays in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/).

Comment: @user3038378 same way

Comment: @alecbenzer Now it is ok

Comment: @Ruchira well, that's still only valid as a parameter to a function. You can't declare an array in C++ like `int x[];`, you need to give a size like `int x[5];` or use an initializer list `int x[] = {1,2,3};`

Answer (score 0):

it is an instatiation of an array of Node objects called vList.  It is initialized to null, unless it is in a method, then it would cause a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
Node *vlist = NULL; // actually, vlist is an Array in 
                    // java that is an object type as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

A few interpretations are plausible.

`Node* vList;` will declare a variable that can hold an array. So like in Java you might see

```
Node[] vList = new Node[5];
```

which works like

```
Node* vList = new Node[5];
```

A better approach in C++ would be to use a vector:

```
std::vector<Node> vList;
```

Note that all objects in Java are references, so a `std::vector<Node*>` or `std::vector<Node&>` may be more appropriate.